# Is Primefaces DataGrid able for lazy loading?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datagrid, lazy-loading

I created some development startup code with the generjee online tool.

Have selected DataGrid for the data list style and have choosen lazy loading for some entities.

Now I'm wondering if Primefaces DataGrid is really able to lazily load the data? In the Primefaces DataGrid Showcase there is nothing about lazy loading. Is this feature supported? I'm new to Faces.

Comment: I really mean JSF lazy loading as supported by Primefaces DataTable: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml

Comment: generjee produces `lazy="true"` and `value="#{chapterBean.lazyModel}"`. Because this works, I suppose PrimeFaces DataGrid supports JSF lazy loading, although it is not in the showcase.

Answer (score 1):

Yes PrimeFaces can do lazy loading, for this, you have to put the attributes.

Here is an example of a lazy DataGrid :

```
<p:dataGrid var="car" value="#{carBean.cars}" columns="3" rows="12"
paginator="true" lazy="true">
...
</p:dataGrid>
```

**value="#{carBean.cars}" :** list of backing Bean
**lazy="true" :** allow lazy loading
**rows="12" :** Number of items to load in lazy
**paginator="true" :** Activate pagination